# Android TicTacToe - random game endings

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

So today I was making TicTacToe for learning purposes, everything seemed good until i tried playing it myself - at some cases game ends before it should. Let's say this is my tictactoe grid:

```
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
```

So for example when i place X at 2 and O game suddenly endes concluding that player 2 (O user) won.

Here's my function for finding out if somebody won. I'm probably silly for doing calculations like this, but i don't really know any other methods of finding when somebody won and deciding who is the winner. Just simple 8 if statements on all possible outcomes which includes winner.

(plr1, plr2 - String with values of "X" and "O", text1,2,3 are textviews for X and O and they are arranged same as in grid above)

```
if(text1.getText().toString() == text2.getText().toString() && text2.getText().toString() == text3.getText().toString()) {
        if(text1.getText().toString() == plr1) {
            status.setText("Player 1 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
        else if(text1.getText().toString() == plr2){
            status.setText("Player 2 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
    }
    else if(text4.getText().toString() == text5.getText().toString() && text5.getText().toString() == text6.getText().toString()) {
        if(text4.getText().toString() == plr1) {
            status.setText("Player 1 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
        else if(text1.getText().toString() == plr2){
            status.setText("Player 2 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
    }
    else if(text7.getText().toString() == text8.getText().toString() && text8.getText().toString() == text9.getText().toString()) {
        if(text1.getText().toString() == plr1) {
            status.setText("Player 1 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
        else if(text1.getText().toString() == plr2){
            status.setText("Player 2 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
    }
    else if(text1.getText().toString() == text4.getText().toString() && text4.getText().toString() == text7.getText().toString()) {
        if(text1.getText().toString() == plr1) {
            status.setText("Player 1 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
        else if(text1.getText().toString() == plr2){
            status.setText("Player 2 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
    }
    else if(text2.getText().toString() == text5.getText().toString() && text5.getText().toString() == text8.getText().toString()) {
        if(text1.getText().toString() == plr1) {
            status.setText("Player 1 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
        else if(text1.getText().toString() == plr2){
            status.setText("Player 2 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
    }
    else if(text3.getText().toString() == text6.getText().toString() && text6.getText().toString() == text9.getText().toString()) {
        if(text1.getText().toString() == plr1) {
            status.setText("Player 1 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
        else if(text1.getText().toString() == plr2){
            status.setText("Player 2 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
    }
    else if(text1.getText().toString() == text5.getText().toString() && text5.getText().toString() == text9.getText().toString()) {
        if(text7.getText().toString() == plr1) {
            status.setText("Player 1 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
        else if(text7.getText().toString() == plr2){
            status.setText("Player 2 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
    }
    else if(text3.getText().toString() == text5.getText().toString() && text5.getText().toString() == text7.getText().toString()) {
        if(text1.getText().toString() == plr1) {
            status.setText("Player 1 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
        else if(text1.getText().toString() == plr2){
            status.setText("Player 2 won!");
            gameRunning = false;
        }
    }
```

Problem logically should be at if statements, but for me they seem okay, maybe I'm missing something, because currently is midnight here.

Comment: Do you remember to re-initialize your grid cells after the first game?

Comment: If you mean after resetting game and doing another "round" - I haven't gone that far yet, I'm restarting whole app to reset it.

Comment: Perhaps then you can step through your test case and isolate the scenario(s) where the game ends prematurely. Also, doesn't your long if... else if chain need an else at the end that would allow the game to continue if the end condition hasn't been met?

Comment: Don't think so, since as long as "gameRunning" boolean isn't changed to false, game shouldn't end.

Comment: You were comparing strings with == instead of equals.

Comment: Is that wrong? I transferred to Java/Android from C++ without doing any studies on its syntax and things like these, in c++ as far as i remember I can compare strings like that with no problem.

Comment: `in c++ as far as i remember I can compare strings like that with no problem` But **C++ != Java**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comparing strings you get from `TextView`s is a performance bottleneck (even if done only a few times) and, more generally, not good practise. As you showed, your TicTacToe grid could fit in a 3x3 array, that could be defined as such: `byte[][] grid = new byte[3][3];`. A `byte` is enough as a grid square can only have 3 states: empty (e.g.`0`), X (`1`), and O (`2`).

Checking for winners is then easier, cleaner and faster:

1. Check for horizontal wins

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       if ((grid[0][i] == grid[1][i]) && (grid[1][i] == grid[2][i])) {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Check for vertical wins (for each column...)
3. Check for the 2 diagonal wins (which is loopable but not worth it for a fixed 3×3 board)

In each case of a win, just take any value from the winning line to determine who won.

Comment: What I personally did with the 3x3 tic tac toe victory detection was that I stored the 2D grid in a 1D array (of 9, of course), and just stored the indices of the lines (such as, 0,1,2; 0,4,8; ... there were 8 of them) on which if the three numbers are 1 or 2, then the given player is victorious. Both solutions are perfectly fine, in fact, yours can be extended in a general manner.